# Momentjs with Typescript : "type string is not assignable to type 'Date'"

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

Till now I was using momentjs library like this:

```
import * as moment from 'moment'; // import moment.
@Component({..});
export class TestClass {
  lastUpdated = Date
  constructor(private myService: MyService){
    this.lastUpdated = this.getCurrentTime(); **// this shows error.. that type string is not assignable to type 'Date'**
  }
 var getCurrentTime(){
    return moment().format('DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss'); 
 }
}
```

Above code shows me this error: that type string is not assignable to type 'Date'**

But same code exactly working fine when I use this line in place of the import module, evenn other resturent os

> declare var moment: any;

But I canot use above statement as it is using "var": and 'any' 
is not suggested by Lint.

Why getCurrentTime is returning String? Should not this return Date

Comment: Change lastUpdated = Date to lastUpdated: moment()

Comment: sorry change it to lastUpdated = moment();

Comment: `getCurrentTime()` returns a string b/c moment's `format()` method returns a string. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: The whole purpose of `format` is to return formatted string. What would 'formatted Date' look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> “type string is not assignable to type 'Date'”

`lastUpdated = Date` should be `lastUpdated: string`.

## Code

Fixed a few other things as well:

```
import * as moment from 'moment'; // import moment.
@Component({..});
export class TestClass {
  lastUpdated: string;
  constructor(private myService: MyService){
    this.lastUpdated = this.getCurrentTime();
  }
 getCurrentTime(){
    return moment().format('DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss'); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can avoid calling one more function by the below code

```
import * as moment from 'moment'; // import moment.
@Component({..});
export class TestClass {
  lastUpdated: string;
  constructor(private myService: MyService){
    this.lastUpdated = moment(this.lastUpdated).format('DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `moment(this.lastUpdated)` should be `moment()`.